# INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE with WHERE?

Tags: mysql, replication

I'm doing a `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` but I need the update part to be conditional, only doing the update if some extra condition has changed.

However, `WHERE` is not allowed on this `UPDATE`. Is there any workaround for this?

I can't do combinations of INSERT/UPDATE/SELECT since this needs to work over a replication.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

I suggest you to use IF() to do that.

Refer: [conditional-duplicate-key-updates-with-mysql](https://thewebfellas.com/blog/conditional-duplicate-key-updates-with-mysql)

```
INSERT INTO daily_events (created_on, last_event_id, last_event_created_at)
  VALUES ('2010-01-19', 23, '2010-01-19 10:23:11')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
  last_event_id = IF(last_event_created_at < VALUES(last_event_created_at), VALUES(last_event_id), last_event_id);
```

Comment: I never knew I could access the original table value inside the UPDATE-part. This probably solves my problem (although my old work around is pretty good :))

Comment: It may happen that MySQL will complain about 'column in field list is ambiguous' - then you'd need to use:  
`ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE  
  daily_events.last_event_id = IF(daily_events.last_event_created_at < VALUES(last_event_created_at), VALUES(last_event_id), daily_events.last_event_id);`

Comment: The link posted to thewebfellas.com is dead, sadly.

Comment: The link posted to thewebfellas.com is now viable

Answer (score 13):

This is our final solution, works like a charm!

The **insert ignore** will make sure that the row exists on both the master and slave, in case they've ever diverted.

The **update ... where** makes sure that only the most recent update, globally, is the end result after all replication is done.

```
mysql> desc test;
+-------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+-------+
| Field | Type         | Null | Key | Default           | Extra |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+-------+
| id    | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL              |       | 
| value | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL              |       | 
| ts    | timestamp    | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |       | 
+-------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+-------+

mysql> insert ignore into test values (4, "foo", now());    
mysql> update test set value = "foo", ts = now() where id = 4 and ts <= now();
```

Comment: The explanation is in the @lexu answer: two statements, the first is `insert ignore`, the second is something like `update ignore`.

Comment: Looks like the second statement is just doing `update test set value = "foo", ts = now() where id = 4 and ts < now()` except in a very convoluted way.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I've since posting this answer changed the code to be `insert ignore...` followed by an `update .... where ts < now()`

Comment: @AndreasWederbrand could you update your answer accordingly, so others may benefit from your conclusions as well?

Answer (score 3):

you could use two insert statements .. since you CAN add a where clause to the select part for the source data.

select two sets of data, one that you will insert with 'on duplicate' and the other will be inserted without 'on duplicate'.

Answer (score 2):

### Overview

- AWUpsertCondy wants to change **BEFORE** into **AFTER**

[image: SimplifiedProblemIllustration]

### Problem

- AWUpsertCondy does not want the insert query to fail if MySQL detects duplicate primary key
- MySQL does not support conditional WHERE clause with `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`

### Solution

- MySQL supports conditional clause with the `IF()` function
- Here we have a simple conditional to update only those items with userid less-than 9

```
INSERT INTO zzdemo_table02
    (lname,userid)
  SELECT
    lname,userid
    FROM(
      SELECT
        lname,userid
      FROM
        zzdemo_table01
    ) as tt01
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    userid=IF(@doupdate:=IF( (tt01.userid < 9) , True, False), 
        tt01.userid, zzdemo_table02.userid)
    ,lname=IF(@doupdate, tt01.lname , zzdemo_table02.lname )
;
```

### Pitfalls

- We introduce a MySQL variable `@doupdate` in order to flag whether or not the UPDATE row meets the condition. Then we use that same variable for all the database columns we use in the UPDATE statement
- In the first conditional we both declare the variable and determine whether the conditional applies. This approach is arguably more cumbersome than a WHERE clause

### See also

- [MySQL copy column withtout conditional](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56566608/42223)

Answer (score 0):

> table `php_lock`:
>  `name`:idString, `locked`:bool,
>   `time`:timestamp, `locked_by`:string
>  values to insert or
>   update
>  1, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'script'
>  where `name`='wwww' AND
>   `locked`=2

```
INSERT INTO `php_lock` (`name`, locked, `time`, `locked_by`)  
(SELECT * FROM 
    (SELECT `name`,1,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'script' FROM `php_lock` 
        WHERE `name`='wwww' AND `locked`=2  
    UNION (
    SELECT 'wwww',1 ,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'script') 
) AS temp LIMIT 1) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE locked=VALUES(locked), `time`=VALUES(`time`), `locked_by`=VALUES(`locked_by`);
```

Answer (score 0):

`On duplicate key` do not allow us to use where clause, so there are two alternative to achieve the same.

1. If you know most of the time you will get the duplicate key then

   `a. Update the table first using update query and where clause
    b. If update fails then insert the record into table using insert query`
2. If you know most of the time you are going to insert into table then

   `a. Insert the record into table using insert ignore query - what it does is actually ignore the insert if duplicate key found
     b. If insert ignore fails then update the record using update query`

For reference of **`insert ignore`** [click here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html)

Comment: How can `insert ignore` fail?

Comment: if you try to insert same unique key `insert ignore` will fail.

Comment: No, thats what `ignore` does. It *ignores* the duplicate key exception.