# how to give where condtion after on duplication key in trigger

Tags: mysql, sql, navicat

The following code is a trigger I wrote in Navicat for Mysql. The inserting part is working correctly but for update I need to update a specific row quantity based on id. How do I write the where clause in the update sql query.

```
insert into closingstockt(CLS_BSID,CLS_Qty,CLS_SQty,CLS_CDate)
select BS_ID as CLS_BSID,BS_Qty as CLS_Qty,BSS_Qty as CLS_SQty,curdate() 
from barstockt
where CLS_BSID=BS_ID 
on duplicate key update CLS_Qty=BS_Qty,CLS_SQty=BSS_Qty
```

Answer (score 0):

`ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` will update the row which already exist in the database. For example:

```
INSERT INTO table (field,field2) VALUES ('data1','data2')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE lastupdate=NOW()
```

EDIT: I suggest to use `IF()`

[INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE with WHERE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2469457/insert-on-duplicate-key-update-with-where)

Comment: i need  update row on bases id is same. like following code but where clause is not allow in On Duplicate Key Update.

insert into closingstockt(CLS_BSID,CLS_Qty,CLS_SQty,CLS_CDate)
select BS_ID as CLS_BSID,BS_Qty as CLS_Qty,BSS_Qty as CLS_SQty,curdate() from barstockt
on duplicate key update  CLS_Qty=BS_Qty,CLS_SQty=BSS_Qty where CLS_BSID=BS_ID

Comment: how i do not know.how to give if condition so can u help for that code

Comment: i check that link but i did not find what actually i am looking.
i need to update all fields base on the id matching in both tables.but i check above link there is no checking that if id is same that row only update not all.