# Mysql insert on duplicate key update with where alternative

Tags: mysql

I would like to know if there is a way to use `insert into...on duplicate key` without use as parameter the primary key of the table, for example I have the following table :

```
+----+------------+------+--------+
| id | product_id | year |  name  |
+----+------------+------+--------+
|  1 |          5 | 2018 | Sword  |
|  2 |          7 | 2018 | Shield |
+----+------------+------+--------+
```

I have an array for insert in that database (PHP - PDO).

This array have 3 items :

- the sword
- the shield
- and the potion

For example, with id as primary key, I would like to know if its possible to perform something like `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` 
instead using the id (because in this moment I'll not have the id)

I can use a `where` or something like that, cross the `product_id` and the `year` would be perfect.

Comment: `on duplicate key` can use any unique key defined on the table.

Comment: yes i know but this work even if i have a constrain for both (product_id and year)? because i can have the same product_id for different years but not for the same year.

Comment: `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE clause` will work only with `UNIQUE index` or `PRIMARY KEY`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE with WHERE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2469457/insert-on-duplicate-key-update-with-where)

Comment: you are absolutely right @DaniyalNasir

Comment: @AugustoCoelhoHenriques Great voteup the comment then :)